# Leaflet: how to change map center and zoom level clicking on circleMarker?

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on a map with a few circleMarkers. When a user is clickin on one of this circleMarker, I would like to center the map on this circleMarker and to zoom in. It works when I try this on multipolygon layers, but I didn't succeed on circleMarkers. Does anyone can help me?

Here is the code for my circleMarkers:

```
    <script>


    var map = L.map('map', { 
        center: [41.8, 12.5],
        zoom: 5,
        zoomControl:true, maxZoom:15, minZoom:4,
        });
var feature_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
var raster_group = new L.LayerGroup([]);

var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri',
});
basemap.addTo(map);


    function style1(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            radius: 10,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'black',
            weight: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: 'red'
        };
    }                               

    L.geoJson(villes, {
        style: style1,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
            {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng).bindLabel( feature.properties.Name, {className: "ville", noHide: true });

            }           
            }
    )

                            .addTo(map)
                            .showLabel; 


</script>.
```

[Here](http://jbouffand.free.fr/cartes/romanisation/index.html) is a link to the complete map.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You say that you can do it on other vector layers. It would help in getting a personalized answer if you could provide the code that you use for that case. Even better, if you could reproduce your issue online (e.g. using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/2/)) you would help other people in understanding your issue and providing you support quicker.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved really simply.
Let's assume `marker` points to your leaflet marker and `map` to your leaflet map.

**Quick way (recommended)**

```
marker.on("click", function(event) {
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), 16);
}, marker);
```

Here, I don't even compute the needed zoom level, because I assume leaflet will have to zoom to its max level anyway.

I could also have added my marker to a `L.LayerGroup`, even if the main point of a `LayerGroup` is to group multiple markers.

Anyhow, **the more precise way**

```
marker.on("click", function(event) {
    map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), map.getBoundsZoom(layerGroup.getBounds());
}, marker);
```

Note that the quick way will do it nicely too. The second solution might seem more precise but it also slower, and implies a use of `LayerGroup` which is not the way it has been designed to work (create a new layergroup for each marker).

Don't forget to take yout time reading the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html), it's well-designed and pretty easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you Stranded Kid. I'll try your solution as soon as possible monday (I'm not at work). I'm pretty sure it will work. I tried several way, but I never thought to write 'marker.on'!

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't succeed. I don't know where I must write your code. I tried every solution I can imagine, placing your code absolutely everywhere. I'm not a specialist of java and leaflet. I read the doc, but I'm not a specialist of java and leaflet. If I dont see a complete sample, I don't know how to associate all this pieces of code. Can you tell me please where I must write your code in mine.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I find the solution:

```
    function onClick(e) {map.setView(this.getLatLng(),15);}

    L.geoJson(villes, {
        style: style1,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
            {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng).bindLabel( feature.properties.Name, {className: "ville", noHide: true }).on('click', onClick);

            }           
            }
    )
                            .addTo(zoom1)
                            .showLabel;
```

Thanks Stranded Kid for your help.